# Confidence interval and p.values for difference between means with summarize function and tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to figure out how to turn a data frame from long to wide, while grouping by two variables (diamond cut and colors D and F from diamonds df) and summarizing some key features of the data at the same time.

Specifically, I am trying to get the difference between two means, 95% CI and p-values around that difference.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bRQKBOywduw4oXTgJPOcK9eewKUI-q4pZMqSq-yZDO4/edit?usp=sharing) is an example of my desired output table (in red is what I am trying to accomplish).

Sample code below, showing how far I've gotten:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Build summary data

diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  select(cut, depth, color) %>% 
  filter(color == "F" | color == "D") %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(depth), #calculate mean & CIs
            lower_ci = mean(depth) - qt(1- 0.05/2, (n() - 1))*sd(depth)/sqrt(n()),
            upper_ci = mean(depth) + qt(1- 0.05/2, (n() - 1))*sd(depth)/sqrt(n()))

# Turn table from long to wide

diamonds <- dcast(as.data.table(diamonds), cut ~ color, value.var = c("mean", "lower_ci", "upper_ci"))

# Rename & calculate the mean difference

diamonds <- diamonds %>%
  rename(
    Cut = cut,
    Mean.Depth.D = mean_D,
    Mean.Depth.F = mean_F,
    Lower.CI.Depth.D = lower_ci_D,
    Lower.CI.Depth.F = lower_ci_F,
    Upper.CI.Depth.D = upper_ci_D,
    Upper.CI.Depth.F = upper_ci_F) %>% 
  mutate(Mean.Difference = Mean.Depth.D - Mean.Depth.F)

# Re-organize the table

diamonds <- subset(diamonds, select = c(Cut:Mean.Depth.F, Mean.Difference, Lower.CI.Depth.D:Upper.CI.Depth.F))

#Calculate the CIs (upper and lower) and p.values for mean difference for each cut and insert them into the table.

?
```

I think I am supposed to calculate the CIs and p-values mean difference in depth between colors D and F at some point before I summarize, but not exactly sure how.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using the t.test function to get the confidence intervals and p-values?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think t.test function could work, but I don't know exactly when I would call for it and how I would pick specific outputs of the test and store them in my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get comparisons of means (with t-tests) for D and F colours across different values for `cut`, this is what you would need to do:

```
library(broom)

diamonds %>% 
   filter(color %in% c("D", "F")) %>% 
   group_by(cut) %>% 
   do( tidy(t.test(data=., depth~color)))
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. But how would I extract the p.value and CIs and match them to my existing dataframe? My ideal scenario is shown here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bRQKBOywduw4oXTgJPOcK9eewKUI-q4pZMqSq-yZDO4/edit#gid=0

Comment: Here is the error that I am getting when running the output wrapped in c(): Error in names(IND) <- deparse(substitute(INDICES))[1L] : 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Comment: @RakhimRakhimov it seems to me that my output looks almost exactly like your requested output.  I can't see what you want to match to?  In my edit the first column (actually the rownames) contains the values for the stratification variable, which is the first column in your outcome spreadsheet.  All the other elements are there.

Comment: @RakhimRakhimov - apologies I didn't realise `diamonds` was a tidyverse dataset.  I'll update my answer!

Comment: @RakhimRakhimov - updated.  Apologies again for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you George, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hi George, I've been beating my head around another issue: how do I add standard deviation of the two means in the table? Tried the summarise(sd(depth)), but doesn't seem to work