# Use dplyr or lapply to run a t.test across multiple groups

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

`DF <- data.frame(ID = c(rep("A", 25),rep("B", 25)), sp = rep(1:5, 10), y = rnorm(50, 1, 1))`

I want to run a t.test between A and B when they have the same 'sp' (1:5), using y as the data.
I haven't come across lapply that uses two grouping factors.

A less elegant solution would be to split the dataframe into 5 and use lapply across A and B, but I'm looking for more simplistic code.

Thanks!

Comment: What would you want your final output to look like? A list of the full t.test object, a data frame of the p values, etc?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean about needing "lapply that uses two grouping factors" or using "lapply across A and B." Wouldn’t `lapply(split(DF, DF$sp), \(x) t.test(y ~ ID, data = x)` give you what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R t.test group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616489/r-t-test-group-by) (or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552284/confidence-interval-and-p-values-for-difference-between-means-with-summarize-fun)). Building off of zephyrl, you could try `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(DF, DF$sp), \(x) t.test(y ~ ID, x)))` which will give you all the relevant info in one place

Comment: @zephryl and @ jpsmith, Ah thank you - I should have used a split. However, this outputs an error message of "grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels." I would like an output of the full t.test object, it doesn't need to be stored in a list.

Comment: That error implies that `ID` in your actual data has more than two unique values — you would need to subset to just the two values you want to group by. If you keep having problems, please edit your question to include sample data that reproduces the problem (eg, using `dput()`).

Comment: Simpler: `by(DF, DF$sp, \(X) t.test(y ~ ID, data = X))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this give you the output you're looking for:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix) #provides pipeable functions for base R stat functions

DF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  t_test(y~sp)
```